# View composer runs multiple times, how to reduce to 1

Tags: php, laravel

I made a view composer in Laravel 5. When I use a wildcard *, to add something to all my views, it gets called at least twice. It runs when my master template is loaded, and again when my content page is included. This will give problems in the future, because it executes the query it does multiple times. I was able to fix the multiple querying by storing it in a static variable :

```
class StoreComposer {

    static $composed;

    public function __construct(StoreRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->store = $repository;
    }


    public function compose(View $view)
    {

        if(static::$composed)
        {
            return $view->with('store', static::$composed);
        }


        static::$composed = $this->store->pushCriteria( new WithCategories() )
            ->pushCriteria( new WithSettings() )
            ->applyCriteria()
            ->all();

        $view->with('store', static::$composed);
    }

}
```

My question is, is there a way to make sure it only runs once, no matter how many views I load, or is there another solution to this? The way I fixed it now doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: have you found any new solutions to this problem? I just came across this problem, and realized some of my pages are executing queries a large number of times over, since I utilize so many view includes on every page.

Comment: I haven't found any new solutions for this. I would suggest making a base class for your viewcomposer classes, that handles the storing in static vars.

Comment: thanks for the response. I actually refactored a lot of the queries out to be more explicit and run in the controllers.  View Composers have always felt a little too *magic* to me

Comment: If you do not need the query results on all pages, it is indeed a bit overkill ;). Glad you found a solution that woks for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to make it run once, due to the way View Composers are implemented. The [`Illuminate\View\View::renderContents()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/View/View.php#L102) method is responsible for calling the composer bound to a view, and since any form of view rendering (Blade template inheritance or simple `@include` statements) executes that method, it means that when any view is rendered any composer bound to it gets triggered.

Since in your case you use a `*` wildcard to bind all views, if your page renders ten views, the composer will get executed ten times. However your approach looks like a good solution to solve this shortcoming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use config here to resolve multiple times query run issue for example show below code.

public function compose(View $view)
{

```
if(!Config::has('composeVars')) 
{
    Config::set('composeVars') = [
      'data' => User::all();  
    ];
}

$view->with('*', Config::get('composeVars'));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this singleton solution or use cache https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/executing-a-view-composer-only-once

On Laravel 5.6.38 works fine